# jQuery ajax find match in ajax results

Tags: jquery, regex, ajax, find, match

Once again regex get's me into trouble.

I am making a ajax call, and in the results I am trying to find a match and append it to the head, on the current page.

Offcourse this is a very simplified example, but I am just trying to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
$.ajax({
    url: destinationUrl,
    success: function(results) {

        var matchToFind = '<link rel="stylesheet" id="elementor-post-510-css" href="http://localhost/webshop/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-510.css?ver=1590740787" type="text/css" media="all">';

        $(results).find(matchToFind);

        $(matchToFind).appendTo('head');

    }
});
```

The matchToFind variable is where the regex part takes place I would think. It is always the same except for the digits. The other parts are also unclear to me. Is it .filter .match .find .closest or what should that combination look like? If this explanation is unclear please let me know. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: There is very little chance you can regex such a string. Instead use DOM - your $(result) is a jQuery object, not an array or a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a string instead of an element

Try this

```js
$.ajax({
  url: destinationUrl,
  success: function(results) {
    $(results).find("#elementor-post-510-css").appendTo('head');
  }
});
```

See:

```js
const results = `<head><link rel="stylesheet" id="elementor-post-510-css" href="http://localhost/webshop/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-510.css?ver=1590740787" type="text/css" media="all"></head>`;
console.log(
  $(results).find("#elementor-post-510-css")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Offcourse. How could I miss the fact that it has and ID. You are my hero @mplungjan ! But I had to change .find to .filter `$(results).filter("#elementor-post-510-css").appendTo('head');` The next challenge will be to get the unique ID digit somehow.